# Unknown entity Id

Tags: java, android

I created a normal button in main.XML and in Java I added added a Toast message when clicking it. My problem is I need to hide it when clicked, but that involves R.id.main or something like that. The problem is I get the error "Unknown entity 'id'". Am I missing imports?

Imports:

```
package com.redstonelamp.DroidRedstoneLamp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View. *;
```

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void confirmClicked(View view){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please choose a version to download",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is in your XML.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide your button you have two possibilities :

**1. With a Listener**

Let's say you have this XML file :

> *main.xml*

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/my_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

In your main class you will need to retrieve your **Button** and subscribe your **MainActivity** to the *click event* of this button.

> *MainActivity*

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.onClickListener
    {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // this will inflate all the UI elements you have added
            // in your main.xml file
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            // here you retrieve the button in the layout by its ID
            Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.my_button);

            // here you tell your button he should propagate the
            // Click event to this Activity.
            myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            // here you handle the click
            // the view parameter is the view that was clicked
            // therefore your button :)
            // so all you have to do is to set it's visibility
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

---

**2. Directly by naming the method**

The mechanism behind is the same but this one allows you to have a custom method name. To do this you will have to add a field in the XML file named : `onClick`.

This field will contain the name of the method that will handle the click.

This method has to be implemented in the **Activity** / **Fragment** in which you have inflated this **Button** (with the `setContentView` method).

> *main.xml*

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/my_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="myOnClickMethod" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Then in your MainActivity :

> *MainActivity*

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.onClickListener
    {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // this will inflate all the UI elements you have added
            // in your main.xml file
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }

        public void myOnClickMethod(View view)
        {
            // here you handle the click
            // the view parameter is the view that was clicked
            // therefore your button :)
            // so all you have to do is to set it's visibility
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Cheers